# Aspose excel wrapText in a merged Cell

Tags: excel, aspose

This issue is occurred in Excel, but this issue became explicit during Aspose update.

Rendering an excel,

Set the A0 IsWrapText to true.

Put value at A0 with value "Hello\nWorld", then merge with A1.

The output of the excel didn't cater the wrapText correctly as it is a merged cell.

P.S. the old version (4.4 or something lower) actually has no this issue, as the AutoFitHeight is not executed by default, thus no change to cell height and the cell height can be growth with the content [catered the \n])

Is there anyway wrapText can be rendered correctly even in a merged cell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in newer versions of Aspose.Cells, you may try to add the following lines of code (after applying style/formatting to the merged cell) to auto-adjust row(s) height for merged cells accordingly:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
.............
AutoFitterOptions options = new AutoFitterOptions();
            options.AutoFitMergedCells = true;
            worksheet.AutoFitRows(options);
........
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: hey, it worked. I am very curious, do Excel has the identical function like that? ( as i tried at excel and the auto fit sheet's rows or fiting one by one are also unable to handle the height of merged cell). Aspose offer this function which is more powerful than the original excel lol

Comment: is it correct to say that new version of aspose will always do the AutoFitRows with OnlyAuto equals to true? (as i can see it behaving like that

Comment: I do not think the new version will auto-fit rows with OnlyAuto option to true, the default value should be false. If you see this behavior, share the sample code and template file, we will check it soon.

Comment: no, i pretty sure it has default AutoFitRow in the newer version

Comment: i dont know how to share the code to you, but you can simulate the case pretty easy. you can put long string in a cell with IsTextWrapped equals to true. Without explicitly AutoFitRow, the old version will NOT adjust the height of that cell, but the newer version will adjust the height (without explicitly AutoFitRow)

Comment: i am comparing the version between 4.4.0.5 and 17.11.0.0

Comment: Well, v4.4.0.5 is quite an older version, so, I guess, may be some change in the behavior (regarding auto-fit operation(s)) in newer versions as over the years we have enhanced existing features in the APIs.

Comment: ya and my task is to update 4.4.0.5 to 17.11.0.0 :D, nvm thanks